# MS Graph API returns 500 internal server error when querying sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

#### Short description:

I have tried to query sites from my test sharepoint: {my_name}.sharepoint.com using the REST interface natively from an http request and also by using the Graph SDK. Authentication goes fine, I am able to acquire a token using both methods. I have already made an app registration, granted permissions and provided admin consent for them on portal.azure.com.

#### Authentication:

**http request code:**

```
                FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {                 
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", $"{ClientId}"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecret)
                });
                string url = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                Console.WriteLine(url);
                var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
                message.Content = content;
                message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                message.Headers.Accept.Clear();
                message.Headers.Accept.TryParseAdd("application/json");
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);
```

**Graph SDK code:**

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication app = 
                ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{GetWWWAuthResponseHeaders(domain)["Bearer realm"]}")
                ).Build();
                var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }).ExecuteAsync();

 

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage => {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                })
            );
```

#### The request producing the error:

**native http code:**

```
                string url = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{Domain}:/sites/{Site}";
                Console.WriteLine($"url: {url}");
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {Token.Token}");
                request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Graph SDK Code:**

```
var site = graphClient.Sites[$"{my_name}.sharepoint.com"].Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

**The exact error I get:**

```
ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: An unspecified error has occurred.
Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
    date: 2021-02-05T10:02:19
    request-id: a3567eca-3d3b-4617-b877-e8f7369660b3
    client-request-id: a3567eca-3d3b-4617-b877-e8f7369660b3
ClientRequestId: a3567eca-3d3b-4617-b877-e8f7369660b3
```

Comment: Baliant, Outside of your application try repro the issue using POSTMAN/Graph Explorer with the same Graph API call and see if you can still repro the issue or not. I tried but i failed to repro the issue at my end.

Comment: As you are using client credential grant, take that token and call this Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/domain.sharepoint.com` by using curl or POSTMAN and see the results.

Comment: I am getting the same 500 Internal Server error from Postman as well.

As per the collection, I am able to get the token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{TenantID}}/oauth2/v2.0/token

I am calling https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{{Domain}}.sharepoint.com and getting the 500. I checked my token on jwt.io and it looks fine to me, and if I purposefully mess the token up, I get 401 as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I test with this code, it works well.

```
            string clientID = "cde921c5-cccc-4264-a450-6daceb46fec5"; // Put the Application ID from above here.
            string clientSecret = "clientSecret "; // Put the Client Secret from above here.

            string graphApiResource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            Uri microsoftLogin = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/");
            string tenantID = "2e83cc45-652e-cccc-a85a-80c981c30c09"; // Put the Azure AD Tenant ID from above here.

            // The authority to ask for a token: your azure active directory.
            string authority = new Uri(microsoftLogin, tenantID).AbsoluteUri;
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);

            // Picks up the bearer token.
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphApiResource, clientCredential).Result;

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    // This is adding a bearer token to the httpclient used in the requests.
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
                }));

            var site = graphClient.Sites["contoso.sharepoint.com"].Request().GetAsync().Result;
```

**Updated:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try! Could you provide me with the using statements please? I am seeing that 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.ClientCredential' is obsolete and does not have a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to run the code, but I am still facing with the same 500 Internal server error. Is there anything on Azure AD or Sharepoint that could cause this?

`ServiceException: Code: generalException
Message: An unspecified error has occurred.
Inner error:
 AdditionalData:
 date: 2021-02-08T09:19:40
 request-id: 235137f5-acc2-443b-9085-82e099fb9afc
 client-request-id: 235137f5-acc2-443b-9085-82e099fb9afc
ClientRequestId: 235137f5-acc2-443b-9085-82e099fb9afc
`

Comment: Can you get the value normally by testing this API in graph explorer? 5xx http status codes are usually server problems.